# Can you sort one column lexicographically while simultaneously sorting the next column numerically?

Tags: sort

I've got two columns of data I need to sort: the first column(A) needs to be sorted lexicographically and for any rows which then contain the same column A string, I need them to be sorted numerically according to what's in the second column(B).

I was thinking    `'sort -f'` , but that would make a '12' in column B come before a '2'.

Edit: Accidentally typed column in place of row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to sort on two fields, second then first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52762/trying-to-sort-on-two-fields-second-then-first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using the `-k` option to define sort keys, and the `n` option to specify numerical sorts:

```
$ echo -e "a 13\nb 2\na 2" | sort -k1,1 -k2,2n
a 2
a 13
b 2
```