# KEYDEF of sort man page

Tags: sort

I have read [Trying to sort on two fields, second then first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52762/376521). I am still confused.

In the `man sort` page:

```
KEYDEF  is  F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position
```

Why there are two `OPTS`?

Does it mean you can write `OPTS` at any place? Or do the two `OPTS` affect different fields?

But isn't the key (e.g. `-k3,5`) function as a whole?

What will happen if the two `OPTS` are opposite? Such as:

```
sort -t " " -k3n,5nr filename
```

The other question is that `-k3n,5nr` contains two white-spaces, how can the shell translate that into a number?

When we want to compare multi fields, should we use multi `-k` (e.g. `-k3` `-k4` `-k5`)? Is `-k3n,5n` wrong?

Comment: Please give an example input and output of what it is you want to do in the "other question" part. For the first, from [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html): "[options] shall have this effect if specified with field_start, field_end, or both."

Comment: @muru solved in the Stephen Kitt answer below.

Comment: _However, fields that extend to the end of the line, as -k 2, or fields consisting of a range, as -k 2,3, retain the field separators present between the endpoints of the range._
[the GNU sort manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#index-sort)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `sort` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) describes this in a little more detail:

> The `'b'` modifier shall behave like the **-b** option, but shall apply only to the *field_start* or *field_end* to which it is attached. The other modifiers shall behave like the corresponding options, but shall apply only to the key field to which they are attached; they shall have this effect if specified with *field_start*, *field_end*, or both.

So you can add options in either position, and they apply to the whole key. They are cumulative, and I think the last one wins in case of conflict.

If you want to compare multiple numeric fields, you should specify them as separate keys; [the GNU `sort` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) says

> For the large majority of applications, treating keys spanning more than one field as numeric will not do what you expect.

Comment: So, you mean that I cannot give 2 different options - one to start field and one to end field ? When I run `sudo ls -l /etc | head -n 10 | sort -k 5n,6M` I am getting error - `sort: options '-Mn' are incompatible`.

Comment: `-k` defines *one* sort key, and a key can only be used to sort one way — so you can sort numerically and by month. But you *can* define multiple sort keys: `-k5,5n -k6,6M`.